# Undefined property: core::#$_news

Tags: php, web, encoding

Hello I am trying to fix my website but I am receiving

> ***Notice: Undefined property: core::$_news in C:\xampp\htdocs\library\class\core.oraios.class.php on line 79***

This is the code at line 79:

```
$this->_news.="<div id='tab$j' class='otherC'><ul>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems `$this->_news` was not yet initialized before you did `$this->_news.="";` .
> You may initialize it like so: `$this->_news   = "";` 
> And,  afterwards you may append to it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it